# Efficient way of integrating a 2-dimensional Gaussian over a convex polygonal domain

Tags: statistics, reference-request, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

I am looking for a reference for the calculation of integrals of bivariate normal distributions over (convex) polygons.

$$P\{X\in\mathcal{A}\} = 
\int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^2|\Sigma|}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}dx$$

$$\Omega:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,\,Ax\leq b\}$$

For the case of triangular domains, formulae exist and are used for example in the [polyCub](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polyCub/index.html) R package. The approach can be extended to arbitrary polygons, based on a triangulation of the domain.

I came across a paper [1] from 1978 that seemingly provides a more efficient solution, without the need for a triangulation. Here the integral over the complement of the region is calculated, based on a partitioning to external angular regions. For these semi-analytical solutions using special functions $(\operatorname{erf}, \operatorname{erfc})$ are given.

I was wondering if a more recent work using such an approach exists? The original document is sometimes barely readable due to the scan quality.

[1] A. R. DiDonato, M. P. Jarnagin Jr, and R. K. Hageman, “Computation of the bivariate normal distribution over convex polygons,” DTIC Document, 1978.

Comment: The paper is republished as:

Didonato, A. R., Jarnagin, Jr., M. P., & Hageman, R. K. (1980). Computation of the Integral of the Bivariate Normal Distribution Over Convex Polygons. SIAM Journal on Scientific and Statistical Computing, 1(2), 179–186. doi:10.1137/0901010